# Error: job x doesnt exist

Tags: node.js, kue

Is someone know why this issue my appears and how to catch it? I do not remove any jobs manually, use only `.removeOnComplete(true)` I have some different job processor for the same job `task` with different parameters. May it cause the issue? How to be in this case?

```
queue.create('task', jobData)
    .removeOnComplete(true)
    .priority('normal')
    .attempts(3)
    .save()

queue.process('task', 5, function (job, ctx, done) {
    // First task prcessor
});

queue.process('task', 5, function (job, ctx, done) {
    // Second task prcessor
});
```

Error:

```
Error: job "425596" doesnt exist
     at Command.callback (/home/carmod/www/avitoparser/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/kue/lib/queue/job.js:178:17)
     at normal_reply (/home/carmod/www/avitoparser/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/redis/index.js:714:21)
     at RedisClient.return_reply (/home/carmod/www/avitoparser/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/redis/index.js:816:9)
     at JavascriptRedisParser.Parser.returnReply (/home/carmod/www/avitoparser/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/redis/index.js:188:18)
     at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/home/carmod/www/avitoparser/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:415:12)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/carmod/www/avitoparser/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/redis/index.js:267:27)
     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
```

Comment: Recommend posting this directly on `kue` Github issue tracker: https://github.com/Automattic/kue Stackoverflow requires specific reproduction code in order to answer "Why is this not working" type questions.

Comment: @Alan, I have posted more details for my question, ty. The issue has been posted at Github, but i don't think somebody will answer because of low activity in this repo.

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://github.com/Automattic/kue/issues/430 It looks like there may be an issue with Kue. FWIW, I had several issues with Kue, so I wrote my own.

Comment: Kue leaks keys and it appears to be a known bug. [This](https://github.com/Automattic/kue/pull/710) PR acknowledges the key leakage (and they still are attempting to find a solution it seems)